# ¿Cómo traer datos de json de una pagina con php?

Tags: php, json

Hola estoy tratando de traerme los datos json que aparecen esta página.

https://main.weku.io/@melodyne

la forma con la que intento traer los datos es:

```
    $link = 'https://main.weku.io/@melodyne';
    $link = strtolower($link);
    $link = strip_tags($link);
    $link = trim($link);

    $ch = curl_init($link);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $jsonString = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $user_details = json_decode($jsonString, true);

    var_dump($user_details['global']);
}
```

Lo que obtengo al ejecutarlo:

```
NULL
```

¿Ayuda?

Comment: te saldra nulll porque lo que recoje es html no json :V

Comment: como le hago papu ? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que manejar lo retornado y representarlo como un documento HTML o XML en su totalidad, para lo cuál puedes usar [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/es/class.domdocument.php) de php. Luego para tomar el valor de un etiqueta en particular puedes usar [getElementsByTagName](http://php.net/manual/es/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php):

```
<?
$link = 'https://main.weku.io/@melodyne';
$link = strtolower($link);
$link = strip_tags($link);
$link = trim($link);

$ch = curl_init($link);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$jsonString = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($jsonString);
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('script');
$global = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue; 

$user_details = json_decode($global, true);

//echo ''.$global;
var_dump($user_details['global']);

?>
```

Salida:

```
array(14) { ["current_route"]=> string(9) "@melodyne" ["discussion_idx"]=> array(0) { } ["accounts"]=> array(1) { ["melodyne"]=> array(71) { ["transfer_history"]=> array(0) { } ["last_bandwidth_update"]=> string(19) "2018-12-07T23:26:48" ["vesting_shares"]=> string(18) "55261.990454 VESTS" ["delegated_vesting_shares"]=> string(14) "0.000000 VESTS" ["savings_sbd_seconds_last_update"]=> string(19) "1970-01-01T00:00:00" ["posting"]=> array(3) { ["weight_threshold"]=> int(1) ["account_auths"]=> array(0) { } ["key_auths"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(53) "WKA6WE7JWuKXDt36BmPzzXwmUTKA6LPy6tEQY8FBpVWwaUWpJDYaQ" [1]=> int(1) } } } ["reward_sbd_balance"]=> string(9) "0.000 WKD" ["blog"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(13) "melodyne/test" [1]=> string(23) "melodyne/test-v2-script" [2]=> string(21) "melodyne/test-sccript" } ["witness_votes"]=> array(0) { } ["recovery_account"]=> string(9) "initminer" ["lifetime_market_bandwidth"]=> int(0) ["withdrawn"]=> int(0) ["last_account_update"]=> string(19) "2018-11-30T02:49:24" ["other_history"]=> array(0) { } ["json_metadata"]=> string(85) "{"profile":{"profile_image":"http://verfutbol.live/vendor/images/logo/melodyne.png"}}" ["active"]=> array(3) { ["weight_threshold"]=> int(1) ["account_auths"]=> array(0) { } ["key_auths"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(53) "WKA6BCR9BuwD5ywqC7ghaTsaRUL9RWGwqfW5syhnjwMVCUDVeBU7P" [1]=> int(1) } } } ["posting_rewards"]=> int(0) ["vesting_withdraw_rate"]=> string(14) "0.000000 VESTS" ["guest_bloggers"]=> array(0) { } ["sbd_seconds_last_update"]=> string(19) "1970-01-01T00:00:00" ["created"]=> string(19) "2018-11-30T02:48:21" ["last_post"]=> string(19) "2018-12-07T23:26:27" ["savings_sbd_last_interest_payment"]=> string(19) "1970-01-01T00:00:00" ["name"]=> string(8) "melodyne" ["savings_sbd_balance"]=> string(9) "0.000 WKD" ["witnesses_voted_for"]=> int(0) ["owner_challenged"]=> bool(false) ["voting_power"]=> int(9800) ["to_withdraw"]=> int(0) ["proxy"]=> string(0) "" ["next_vesting_withdrawal"]=> string(19) "1969-12-31T23:59:59" ["vesting_balance"]=> string(10) "0.000 WEKU" ["average_bandwidth"]=> int(1241423327) ["savings_sbd_seconds"]=> string(1) "0" ["reward_vesting_steem"]=> string(10) "0.000 WEKU" ["comment_count"]=> int(0) ["post_count"]=> int(3) ["lifetime_vote_count"]=> int(0) ["average_market_bandwidth"]=> int(0) ["sbd_last_interest_payment"]=> string(19) "1970-01-01T00:00:00" ["last_account_recovery"]=> string(19) "1970-01-01T00:00:00" ["proxied_vsf_votes"]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(0) [2]=> int(0) [3]=> int(0) } ["mined"]=> bool(false) ["last_market_bandwidth_update"]=> string(19) "1970-01-01T00:00:00" ["market_history"]=> array(0) { } ["sbd_balance"]=> string(9) "0.000 WKD" ["owner"]=> array(3) { ["weight_threshold"]=> int(1) ["account_auths"]=> array(0) { } ["key_auths"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(53) "WKA8iEQZuwt66tVq5W97yVWm7WLwCytSrYKV4cjijFHkuQzmWW4uw" [1]=> int(1) } } } ["savings_withdraw_requests"]=> int(0) ["last_root_post"]=> string(19) "2018-12-07T23:26:27" ["sbd_seconds"]=> string(1) "0" ["post_history"]=> array(0) { } ["savings_balance"]=> string(10) "0.000 WEKU" ["last_active_proved"]=> string(19) "1970-01-01T00:00:00" ["reputation"]=> string(11) "37618485231" ["last_vote_time"]=> string(19) "2018-12-07T23:26:48" ["can_vote"]=> bool(true) ["reward_steem_balance"]=> string(10) "0.000 WEKU" ["curation_rewards"]=> int(0) ["memo_key"]=> string(53) "WKA6KSuB5aofhenjcCjEqeiWPxZWmTXMkaxxLgfVPFp91LcSD5mm9" ["active_challenged"]=> bool(false) ["id"]=> int(51164) ["tags_usage"]=> array(0) { } ["lifetime_bandwidth"]=> int(1610000000) ["balance"]=> string(10) "0.000 WEKU" ["reset_account"]=> string(4) "null" ["last_owner_proved"]=> string(19) "1970-01-01T00:00:00" ["last_owner_update"]=> string(19) "1970-01-01T00:00:00" ["vote_history"]=> array(0) { } ["withdraw_routes"]=> int(0) ["received_vesting_shares"]=> string(21) "11000000.000000 VESTS" ["reward_vesting_balance"]=> string(14) "0.000000 VESTS" } } ["witnesses"]=> array(0) { } ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["feed_price"]=> array(2) { ["base"]=> string(9) "1.000 WKD" ["quote"]=> string(10) "1.000 WEKU" } ["community"]=> string(0) "" ["pow_queue"]=> array(0) { } ["pathname"]=> string(10) "/@melodyne" ["props"]=> array(29) { ["max_virtual_bandwidth"]=> string(21) "528482304000000000000" ["current_reserve_ratio"]=> int(200000000) ["virtual_supply"]=> string(18) "450216687.501 WEKU" ["confidential_supply"]=> string(10) "0.000 WEKU" ["num_pow_witnesses"]=> int(0) ["total_reward_fund_steem"]=> string(10) "0.000 WEKU" ["total_reward_shares2"]=> string(1) "0" ["pending_rewarded_vesting_shares"]=> string(24) "90620132058.886015 VESTS" ["sbd_interest_rate"]=> int(1000) ["head_block_id"]=> string(40) "0054da1ddb5e1ecc9fcf688d784fcdf7bbcdbc4d" ["time"]=> string(19) "2018-12-08T18:16:00" ["recent_slots_filled"]=> string(39) "340282366920938463463374607431768211455" ["confidential_sbd_supply"]=> string(9) "0.000 WKD" ["participation_count"]=> int(128) ["vote_power_reserve_rate"]=> int(10) ["maximum_block_size"]=> int(131072) ["current_witness"]=> string(9) "initminer" ["current_supply"]=> string(18) "448397591.959 WEKU" ["average_block_size"]=> int(736) ["pending_rewarded_vesting_steem"]=> string(16) "1605938.355 WEKU" ["current_aslot"]=> int(6375920) ["total_vesting_fund_steem"]=> string(17) "79967287.681 WEKU" ["head_block_number"]=> int(5560861) ["id"]=> int(0) ["last_irreversible_block_num"]=> int(5560861) ["sbd_print_rate"]=> int(10000) ["total_vesting_shares"]=> string(26) "4415198913852.505927 VESTS" ["total_pow"]=> string(20) "18446744073709551615" ["current_sbd_supply"]=> string(15) "1819095.542 WKD" } ["tag_idx"]=> array(1) { ["trending"]=> array(50) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(15) "community-deals" [2]=> string(4) "amar" [3]=> string(7) "zealpro" [4]=> string(4) "weku" [5]=> string(11) "photography" [6]=> string(4) "life" [7]=> string(13) "wekuteamworld" [8]=> string(11) "teamquality" [9]=> string(14) "wekubangladesh" [10]=> string(5) "nirob" [11]=> string(7) "created" [12]=> string(7) "spanish" [13]=> string(8) "acehnese" [14]=> string(4) "blog" [15]=> string(6) "nature" [16]=> string(4) "aceh" [17]=> string(4) "news" [18]=> string(4) "zeal" [19]=> string(7) "writing" [20]=> string(3) "art" [21]=> string(8) "phoketoz" [22]=> string(5) "lifty" [23]=> string(4) "food" [24]=> string(9) "whitelist" [25]=> string(9) "indonesia" [26]=> string(5) "story" [27]=> string(5) "photo" [28]=> string(6) "saahil" [29]=> string(10) "wekufamily" [30]=> string(6) "flower" [31]=> string(11) "weku-create" [32]=> string(9) "weku-team" [33]=> string(6) "poetry" [34]=> string(7) "bitcoin" [35]=> string(11) "phototalent" [36]=> string(14) "cryptocurrency" [37]=> string(8) "wekuteam" [38]=> string(7) "monomad" [39]=> string(12) "weku-nigeria" [40]=> string(8) "weku-edu" [41]=> string(6) "travel" [42]=> string(4) "love" [43]=> string(8) "wekulife" [44]=> string(6) "sports" [45]=> string(18) "zeal-gratefulvibes" [46]=> string(19) "photo-wekuteamworld" [47]=> string(7) "qurator" [48]=> string(19) "story-wekuteamworld" [49]=> string(7) "contest" } } ["tags"]=> array(0) { } ["content"]=> array(3) { ["melodyne/test"]=> array(45) { ["parent_author"]=> string(0) "" ["pending_payout_value"]=> string(9) "0.603 WKD" ["curator_payout_value"]=> string(9) "0.000 WKD" ["root_comment"]=> int(806660) ["body"]=> string(12) "testscript 3" ["body_length"]=> int(0) ["max_accepted_payout"]=> string(15) "1000000.000 WKD" ["beneficiaries"]=> array(0) { } ["depth"]=> int(0) ["promoted"]=> string(9) "0.000 WKD" ["net_rshares"]=> string(12) "802896193676" ["reblogged_by"]=> array(0) { } ["json_metadata"]=> string(75) "{"tags":["community-deals","test"],"app":"steemit/0.1","format":"markdown"}" ["active"]=> string(19) "2018-12-07T23:26:27" ["net_votes"]=> int(2) ["replies"]=> array(0) { } ["reward_weight"]=> int(10000) ["created"]=> string(19) "2018-12-07T23:26:27" ["percent_steem_dollars"]=> int(10000) ["permlink"]=> string(4) "test" ["author"]=> string(8) "melodyne" ["max_cashout_time"]=> string(19) "1969-12-31T23:59:59" ["author_reputation"]=> string(11) "37618485231" ["url"]=> string(31) "/community-deals/@melodyne/test" ["last_payout"]=> string(19) "1970-01-01T00:00:00" ["active_votes"]=> array(0) { } ["author_rewards"]=> int(0) ["allow_curation_rewards"]=> bool(true) ["cashout_time"]=> string(19) "2018-12-14T23:26:27" ["vote_rshares"]=> string(12) "802896193676" ["total_vote_weight"]=> int(907138) ["allow_replies"]=> bool(true) ["last_update"]=> string(19) "2018-12-07T23:26:27" ["allow_votes"]=> bool(true) ["total_payout_value"]=> string(9) "0.000 WKD" ["title"]=> string(4) "test" ["abs_rshares"]=> string(12) "802896193676" ["children_abs_rshares"]=> string(12) "802896193676" ["root_title"]=> string(4) "test" ["id"]=> int(806660) ["total_pending_payout_value"]=> string(10) "0.000 WEKU" ["category"]=> string(15) "community-deals" ["stats"]=> array(9) { ["isNsfw"]=> bool(false) ["hide"]=> bool(false) ["hasPendingPayout"]=> bool(true) ["gray"]=> bool(false) ["flagWeight"]=> int(0) ["up_votes"]=> int(2) ["total_votes"]=> int(2) ["authorRepLog10"]=> int(39) ["allowDelete"]=> bool(false) } ["children"]=> int(0) ["parent_permlink"]=> string(15) "community-deals" } ["melodyne/test-sccript"]=> array(45) { ["parent_author"]=> string(0) "" ["pending_payout_value"]=> string(9) "0.602 WKD" ["curator_payout_value"]=> string(9) "0.000 WKD" ["root_comment"]=> int(800490) ["body"]=> string(126) "Este es un script de prueba. no votar estar publicacion gracias.   This is a test script. do not vote be published thank you." ["body_length"]=> int(0) ["max_accepted_payout"]=> string(15) "1000000.000 WKD" ["beneficiaries"]=> array(0) { } ["depth"]=> int(0) ["promoted"]=> string(9) "0.000 WKD" ["net_rshares"]=> string(12) "801790667477" ["reblogged_by"]=> array(0) { } ["json_metadata"]=> string(75) "{"tags":["community-deals","test"],"app":"steemit/0.1","format":"markdown"}" ["active"]=> string(19) "2018-12-06T18:10:03" ["net_votes"]=> int(2) ["replies"]=> array(0) { } ["reward_weight"]=> int(10000) ["created"]=> string(19) "2018-12-06T18:10:03" ["percent_steem_dollars"]=> int(10000) ["permlink"]=> string(12) "test-sccript" ["author"]=> string(8) "melodyne" ["max_cashout_time"]=> string(19) "1969-12-31T23:59:59" ["author_reputation"]=> string(11) "37618485231" ["url"]=> string(39) "/community-deals/@melodyne/test-sccript" ["last_payout"]=> string(19) "1970-01-01T00:00:00" ["active_votes"]=> array(0) { } ["author_rewards"]=> int(0) ["allow_curation_rewards"]=> bool(true) ["cashout_time"]=> string(19) "2018-12-13T18:10:03" ["vote_rshares"]=> string(12) "801790667477" ["total_vote_weight"]=> int(906611) ["allow_replies"]=> bool(true) ["last_update"]=> string(19) "2018-12-06T18:10:03" ["allow_votes"]=> bool(true) ["total_payout_value"]=> string(9) "0.000 WKD" ["title"]=> string(12) "test sccript" ["abs_rshares"]=> string(12) "801790667477" ["children_abs_rshares"]=> string(12) "801790667477" ["root_title"]=> string(12) "test sccript" ["id"]=> int(800490) ["total_pending_payout_value"]=> string(10) "0.000 WEKU" ["category"]=> string(15) "community-deals" ["stats"]=> array(9) { ["isNsfw"]=> bool(false) ["hide"]=> bool(false) ["hasPendingPayout"]=> bool(true) ["gray"]=> bool(false) ["flagWeight"]=> int(0) ["up_votes"]=> int(2) ["total_votes"]=> int(2) ["authorRepLog10"]=> int(39) ["allowDelete"]=> bool(false) } ["children"]=> int(0) ["parent_permlink"]=> string(15) "community-deals" } ["melodyne/test-v2-script"]=> array(45) { ["parent_author"]=> string(0) "" ["pending_payout_value"]=> string(9) "0.603 WKD" ["curator_payout_value"]=> string(9) "0.000 WKD" ["root_comment"]=> int(805977) ["body"]=> string(41) "TEST V2 SCRIPT DONT VOTE THIS POST THANKS" ["body_length"]=> int(0) ["max_accepted_payout"]=> string(15) "1000000.000 WKD" ["beneficiaries"]=> array(0) { } ["depth"]=> int(0) ["promoted"]=> string(9) "0.000 WKD" ["net_rshares"]=> string(12) "802896193676" ["reblogged_by"]=> array(0) { } ["json_metadata"]=> string(77) "{"tags":["community-deals","script"],"app":"steemit/0.1","format":"markdown"}" ["active"]=> string(19) "2018-12-07T19:03:00" ["net_votes"]=> int(2) ["replies"]=> array(0) { } ["reward_weight"]=> int(10000) ["created"]=> string(19) "2018-12-07T19:03:00" ["percent_steem_dollars"]=> int(10000) ["permlink"]=> string(14) "test-v2-script" ["author"]=> string(8) "melodyne" ["max_cashout_time"]=> string(19) "1969-12-31T23:59:59" ["author_reputation"]=> string(11) "37618485231" ["url"]=> string(41) "/community-deals/@melodyne/test-v2-script" ["last_payout"]=> string(19) "1970-01-01T00:00:00" ["active_votes"]=> array(0) { } ["author_rewards"]=> int(0) ["allow_curation_rewards"]=> bool(true) ["cashout_time"]=> string(19) "2018-12-14T19:03:00" ["vote_rshares"]=> string(12) "802896193676" ["total_vote_weight"]=> int(907138) ["allow_replies"]=> bool(true) ["last_update"]=> string(19) "2018-12-07T19:03:00" ["allow_votes"]=> bool(true) ["total_payout_value"]=> string(9) "0.000 WKD" ["title"]=> string(14) "TEST V2 SCRIPT" ["abs_rshares"]=> string(12) "802896193676" ["children_abs_rshares"]=> string(12) "802896193676" ["root_title"]=> string(14) "TEST V2 SCRIPT" ["id"]=> int(805977) ["total_pending_payout_value"]=> string(10) "0.000 WEKU" ["category"]=> string(15) "community-deals" ["stats"]=> array(9) { ["isNsfw"]=> bool(false) ["hide"]=> bool(false) ["hasPendingPayout"]=> bool(true) ["gray"]=> bool(false) ["flagWeight"]=> int(0) ["up_votes"]=> int(2) ["total_votes"]=> int(2) ["authorRepLog10"]=> int(39) ["allowDelete"]=> bool(false) } ["children"]=> int(0) ["parent_permlink"]=> string(15) "community-deals" } } ["witness_schedule"]=> array(15) { ["next_shuffle_block_num"]=> int(5560843) ["timeshare_weight"]=> int(5) ["current_virtual_time"]=> string(1) "0" ["max_voted_witnesses"]=> int(20) ["max_miner_witnesses"]=> int(0) ["witness_pay_normalization_factor"]=> int(1) ["majority_version"]=> string(6) "0.20.0" ["max_runner_witnesses"]=> int(1) ["miner_weight"]=> int(1) ["hardfork_required_witnesses"]=> int(1) ["current_shuffled_witnesses"]=> string(672) "656e696d74696e6900000000000000720000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" ["top19_weight"]=> int(1) ["id"]=> int(0) ["median_props"]=> array(3) { ["account_creation_fee"]=> string(10) "0.001 WEKU" ["maximum_block_size"]=> int(131072) ["sbd_interest_rate"]=> int(1000) } ["num_scheduled_witnesses"]=> int(1) } }
```

Comment: si ya se que concatenandole el .json te da esos datos json. pero de esta forma te los da incompletos. si te fijas en el surce de la pagina que pongo hay un array ['global'] toda esa info es la que necesito.

Comment: esto es lo que necesito. http://oi66.tinypic.com/f42uiu.jpg

Comment: Ahí edité mi respuesta.

Comment: 7u7r ahora si gracias papu!!

Comment: Hola una ultima consulta. para traer los datos de json_metadata como le hago? intento var_dump($user_details['global']['accounts']['json_metadata']); pero sale Undefined index: json_metadata